# How do I test whether a string contains only numbers and one single spaces using RegEx?

Tags: jquery, regex

i.e.

```
022 61747567 is valid 
02261747567 is valid 
022 6174 7567 is not valid
```

Comment: Would space at the beginning or end be valid as well?

Comment: Also `" "`, `"7"`, `"1 2"`? Should be there exactly eleven digits? Or at least one?

Comment: Does it need to be a regex?  there are JS core function which might validate that aswell? Am asking because u brought in the Jquery Tag aswell...so its about JS

Answer (score 3):

You may try this,

```
^\d+( \d+)?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vP1sF6/2)

- `^` start
- `\d+` one or more digits.
- `( \d+)?` (space and one or more digits) optional.
- `$` End

Use this regex if the space may appear anywhere on the input string.

```
^(?=\d* ?\d*$)(?= *\d)[\d ]+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vP1sF6/3)

Comment: Yep. One thing though - OP didn't state if it's OK to have the space in the beginning or the end. This doesn't allow it.

Comment: I'm not saying it should. It was more of a request to OP to specify ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler regex if the space can appear anywhere in the string:

```
^\d* ?\d*$
```